# flutter checkbox not working in StatelessWidget

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, hybrid-mobile-app

Here is my class

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
```

and the Checkbox goes here.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  TextField(
                      controller: ctrlMotherName,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: "Name of Mother",
                          border: OutlineInputBorder()
                      )
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10,),
                  Checkbox(
                    value: false,
                    onChanged: (bool val){

                    },
                  ),
```

I can't able to check the checkbox. Same issue found when I use Radiobutton also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a `StatefulWidget` since you're dealing with changing values. I've provided an example:

```
class MyAppOne extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyAppOne> {
  bool _myBoolean = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Checkbox(
        value: _myBoolean,
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            _myBoolean = value; // rebuilds with new value
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: But why i can change TextField value without StatefulWidget?

Answer (score 2):

One way you can achieve this is using the `provider` package. I tried to create the shortest possible app to show how you can use it. The neat part is that you get to keep your widget **stateless**.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => CheckboxProvider(),
          child: Consumer<CheckboxProvider>(
            builder: (context, checkboxProvider, _) => Checkbox(
              value: checkboxProvider.isChecked,
              onChanged: (value) {
                checkboxProvider.isChecked = value ?? true;
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CheckboxProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  bool _isChecked = false;

  bool get isChecked => _isChecked;

  set isChecked(bool value) {
    _isChecked = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

It took me quite some time to understand the package but it is very useful and recommended if you want an easier way to manage state in your application. Here's a [video](https://youtu.be/d_m5csmrf7I) from the Flutter team explaining how to use Provider. I would still recommend spending some time looking further into it.

P.S.: Don't forget to change the `pubspec.yaml` file.

Answer (score 0):

think of flutter like javascript and pass the position as a parameter to the medCheckedChanged function in the list builder. when the dart parser evaluates the expression or lambda function it will invoke the method with the position parameter as a value.

```
class testWidget2 extends StatefulWidget {
    testWidget2({Key key}) : super(key: key);
    int numberLines = 50;
    List<bool> checkBoxValues = [];

    @override
   _testWidget2State createState() => _testWidget2State();
 }

 class _testWidget2State extends State<testWidget2> {
   _medCheckedChanged(bool value, int position) {
      setState(() => widget.checkBoxValues[position] = value);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
  // TODO: implement initState
   super.initState();
  int i = 0;
   setState(() {
    while (i < widget.numberLines) {
    widget.checkBoxValues.add(false);
    i++;
   }
   });
  }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Container(
        child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: widget.checkBoxValues.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, position) {
              return Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * .06,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .14,
                alignment: Alignment(0, 0),
                child: Checkbox(
                  activeColor: Color(0xff06bbfb),
                  value: widget.checkBoxValues[position],
                  onChanged: (newValue) {
                    _medCheckedChanged(newValue, position);
                  }, //pass to medCheckedChanged() the position
                ),
              );
            })));
   }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use StateProvider from the Riverpod package to achieve this.

```
final checkboxProvider = StateProvider<bool>((ref) => false);



class CheckboxWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const CheckboxWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Consumer(
            builder: (context, ref, _) {
              return Checkbox(
                value: ref.watch(checkboxProvider),
                onChanged: (value) {
                  ref.read(checkboxProvider.state).state = value!;
                },
              );
            }
        ),
        Text('On'),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```