# Please, how do I embed the blue container in my code

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been working on this project and currently stucked. I have successfully created the first image but finding it difficult to embed the container carrying the 'NEXT' to make it look like the second image. Please any help would be appreciated. My codes is attached here.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

```
class GridViewPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            HeaderWiget(),
            Expanded(child: Product()),
          ],
        
        ),
      
      ),
    );
  }
}


the 'NEXT' code

Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              vertical: 16,
            ),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => GridViewPage()));
              },
              child: Center(
                child: Text('Next',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 22.0,
                        fontFamily: 'Work Sans',
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                        color: Color(0XFF161F51))),
              ),
            ),
          ),





  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8sfH.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dcw1.png



import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:signin1/widget/SelectedDont.dart';

class Product extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProductState createState() => _ProductState();
}

class _ProductState extends State<Product> {
  final listItem = [
    {'Name': 'Hair & Beauty', 'image': 'assets/images/Rectangle15.png'},
    {'Name': 'Wedding planner', 'image': 'assets/images/Rectangle16.png'},
    {'Name': 'Bridal Attire', 'image': 'assets/images/Rectangle17.png'},
    {'Name': 'Catering_1', 'image': 'assets/images/Rectangle18.png'},
    {'Name': 'DJ', 'image': 'assets/images/Rectangle19.png'},
    {'Name': 'Florist', 'image': 'assets/images/Rectangle20.png'},
    {'Name': 'Jewelry', 'image': 'assets/images/Rectangle21.png'},
    {'Name': 'Props', 'image': 'assets/images/Rectangle22.png'},
    {'Name': 'Bridal_Attire', 'image': 'assets/images/Rectangle17.png'},
    {'Name': 'Catering', 'image': 'assets/images/Rectangle18.png'},
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: GridView.builder(
          itemCount: listItem.length,
          gridDelegate:
              SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                child: ProductApp(
                  businessName: listItem[index]['Name'],
                  businessImage: listItem[index]['image'],
                ));
          }),
    );
  }
}



This code below is really messing me up. It's a gridview with a checked button and when checked and scroll downward and upward again, it uncheckes itself. This means, the state is dead when i scroll down to give me a new state. How can I fix this?



class ProductApp extends StatefulWidget {
  final businessName;
  final businessImage;
  ProductApp({this.businessName, this.businessImage});
  @override
  _ProductAppState createState() => _ProductAppState();
}

class _ProductAppState extends State<ProductApp> {
  Color color;
  bool isToggle = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: Hero(
          tag: widget.businessName,
          child: Material(
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  isToggle = isToggle ? false : true;
                });
              },
              child: GridTile(
                child: Image.asset(
                  widget.businessImage,
                  fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                ),
                header: Container(
                  child: ListTile(
                    trailing: SelectedDot(
                        colors: isToggle
                            ? Colors.pink
                            : Colors.black.withOpacity(0.0)),
                    title: Text(
                      widget.businessName,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 12.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it with 'Stack' widget like below.
Here is a full code.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: 50,
                color: Colors.yellow,
                child: Text(
                  'header',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.green)),
            ],
          ),
          Positioned(
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: _buildButton(),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildButton() {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        vertical: 16,
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          // Navigator.push(
          //     context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => GridViewPage()));
        },
        child: Text(
          'Next',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 22.0,
            fontFamily: 'Work Sans',
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
            color: Color(0XFF161F51),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Another thing is after scrolling the state of my widget gets destroyed. Please, how can i keep it the way it is. For instance, if i checked the boxed at tge upper region and then scroll down and up, it will unchecked itself.

Comment: I think you can do by changing from 'Stateless' widget to 'Stateful' widget.

Comment: After making a bool variable to save checkbox state in the stateful widget, and set checkbox's initial value by variable and when you check/uncheck checkbox set variable to that value. If that, although all widget will be re-builded, checkbox variable not disappeared.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59438186/flutter-checkbox-not-working-in-statelesswidget

Comment: For m, I am able to check the boxes but when i scroll down and up, it unchecks itself. I think the state dies as soon as i scroll down.

Comment: The 'ProductApp' state will not be remained when rebuild 'GridViewPage' page.
You need to save that value at the not disposed Statefule widget.

Comment: if i get you right, you mean the productapp should be statefull? I already did.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Stack Widget](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=liEGSeD3Zt8&ab_channel=Flutter) to embed the container in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a Widget over another Widget, you can use the [Stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) widget like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget createBackground() {
    return Container(color: Colors.yellow,);
  }
    
  Widget createForeground() {
    return Center(child: FlatButton(color: Colors.blue, child: Text('Next'), onPressed: () => {}));
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            createBackground(),
            createForeground(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. You guys saved my day.